# Lector de codigo de Barras y Php

Tags: php, nodejs, angular, ionic

me pidieron como trabajo crear un control de stock con lector de código de barras. ¿Quisiera saber si la aplicación se puede hacer en web? ¿O la tengo que hacer nativa obligada mente?

Yo actualmente cuento con conocimientos web, nunca eh explorado el ambiente nativo por tanto tengo mucho desconocimiento.

Mis conocimientos son: PHP, Angular, nodejs, javascript y quiero Aprender Ionic para realizar aplicaciones híbridas para celulares.

¿Conocen la manera de poder integrar el lector en estos lenguajes?

Comment: La pregunta, tal y como está, no me parece adecuada para el sitio [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ... un punto de partida, para que vayas empezando, es que busques información sobre lectores de códigos de barras **que simulen ser un teclado**. Un saludo :-)

Comment: El lector es simplemente un dispositivo de entrada similar a un teclado. No veo ningun problema en la implementacion.

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de lector de códigos de barras quieren usar? ¿Uno físico (USB o bluetooth) o usando la cámara de un móvil? En ambos casos se puede hacer el trabajo a través de una página web, pero dependiendo del lector que se vaya a usar hay que cambiar el enfoque del desarrollo.

Answer (score 2):

Recientemente he trabajado en software industrial para picking de productos con lectores de códigos, más concretamente códigos GS1 Data-matrix y puedo asegurarte que puedes hacerlo con un simple JavaScript, ya que las pistolas lectoras de códigos de barras generalmente funcionan como un teclado al conectarlas al ordenador o tablet. Y simplemente tendrías que capturar esas teclas.

Answer (score 0):

**Requerimiento**

Debes tener en cuenta que para realizar la lectura de un código de barras necesitas de un hardware específico, puedes comenzar con un código de escritura que funciona por una especie de comandos que este le inyecta por así decirlo al sistema operativo.

1. Conectado con USB al cliente
2. Debes tenerlo configurado de acuerdo al tipo de lector (sea 2D para código PDF417 o códigos similares)
3. Acercar el código al lector
4. Si tienes un campo de entrada en el cual el cursor este sobre el ó en un excel verás que la lectura se transfiere al documento.

**Web o Movil**

La respuesta es depende, lo puedes realizar de las dos formas, todo varía es de acuerdo a la necesidad puntual que tengas.

¿Lo bueno?

Como tienes conocimientos web, te va a ser muy fácil la implementación de una aplicación híbrida con Ionic, dado que sabes Angular, por lo que su curva de aprendizaje será mucho más corta, además, actualmente en la versión 4 (Beta) Angular es su cliente más estable.

**Aplicaciones Híbridas**

Las aplicaciones híbridas son aplicaciones móviles diseñadas en un lenguaje de programación web ya sea HTML5, CSS o JavaScript, junto con un framework que permite adaptar la vista web a cualquier vista de un dispositivo móvil. En otras palabras, no son más que una aplicación construida para ser utilizada o implementada en distintos sistemas operativos móviles, tales como, iOS, Android o Windows Phone, evitándonos la tarea de crear una aplicación para cada sistema operativo.

Personalmente pienso que, entre más soluciones le podamos brindar a un cliente, seremos mucho más eficientes. Pero, para realizar esta funcionalidad no debemos usar un lector, debemos desarrollar una aplicación que pueda leer código por medio de su cámara, un ejemplo claro lo puedes encontrar en la documentación oficial de [ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/qr-scanner/)

*Escáner QR*

Un escáner de códigos QR rápido, eficiente en energía y altamente configurable para las aplicaciones Cordova.

Requiere Cordova plugin: `cordova-plugin-qrscanner`.

Para obtener más información, consulte los documentos del complemento del escáner QR: [repositorio qr code](https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner)

---

**Recomendación**

Para que la comunidad reciba de forma correcta la pregunta que estás realizando es bueno que entiendas que el sitio tienen unos parámetros importantes que se deben de seguir:
Para mejorar tus oportunidades de obtener una respuesta, acá hay algunos consejos:

¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?

Busca, e investiga
...y mantén un registro de lo que encuentres. Incluso si no encuentras una respuesta útil en cualquier parte del sitio, incluyendo en los enlaces sobre preguntas relacionadas o que no hayan ayudado pueden ayudar a otros a entender cómo tu pregunta es diferente del resto. Para mayor información [sigue este enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)